# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException only when the array length is equal to one

Tags: android, arrays, listview, cursor, adapter

I've an array that collects the result of a rawQuery. It works perfectly, but when It has only one result throws this exception.

```
public String [][] getList() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String [][] data;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nombre FROM productos GROUP BY " +
            "nombre ORDER BY nombre", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            data = new String[c.getCount()][1];
            int i = 0; char last = 1;
            do {
                data[i][0]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nombre"));
                if(data[i][0].charAt(0)!=last) {
                            char [] a = {data[i][0].charAt(0)};
                String b = new String(a); 
                            data[i][1]=b; 
                            last = a[0];} else {
                    data[i][1]=null;
                }
                i++;
            } while ( c.moveToNext());
            db.close();
            return data;
        }
        data=new String[1][1]; data[0][0]="-1";
        db.close();
        return data;
    }
```

The method provides to the Custom List Adapter the information needed for build the listView with separators (That's why I use chars in the second column). Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing `data` to an array `new String[c.getCount()][1]`. That means that the highest valid second subscript is 0, not 1. You want a two-element array: `new String[c.getCount()][2]`

Comment: Thanks! But the problem persists. When I've for example two results It works perfectly, only fails when has one result.

Comment: I've tried again a now works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Buni - Perhaps you can [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to indicate to others that the problem is solved.